# How to avoid writing many wrappers for identical library methods that do not implement a common interface?

Tags: java, oop, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am working with the AWS SDK for Java, which has a large number of classes that contain common methods, however the common methods do not implement a common interface (or extend from a common base class, etc.)

For instance, I have to write this pattern very frequently:

```
while(true) {
  InformationResult result = client.getInformation(new InformationRequest());
  CustomData data = result.getData(); 
  // do stuff
  if ! result.isTruncated() {
   break;
  }
}
```

I would like to only write this pattern once, however there are many `CustomData` and `InformationResult` classes with no polymorphic relation.

Ideas? I'd like not to wrap all the classes myself.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do or how you are trying to extend it. How do you expect me to answer this?

Comment: I want to abstract the common access pattern for these classes out: there are 50? classes like the above prototype, each with attendant *Request, *Result classes accessing them. I'd like to DRY up the code. :-)

Comment: Amazon has APIs in dozens of languages that are all probably generated from common source.

Comment: @djechlin ya, prolly. On the other hand, I'd like to use them without duplicating common code every time I try to access them. I'm not super expert at Java, so... hence the question. :-)

Comment: Do you know of any benefits for generated code to be DRY or are you just trying to "clean things up"?

Comment: @djechlin - I don't want to modify the AWS classes, I want to not write the (listed) access pattern 20 times across my codebase. In case it's not clear - the pseudocode above has to be done to correctly paginate results as they come in from AWS in many objects.  I would instead like to be able to factor the commonality out somehow in my access code.

Comment: so `isTruncated` is the library method that appears in many classes but does not implement an interface?

Comment: isTruncated, getMarker, and some (name varies) getX function which returns a List<X> from the XResult class.  isTruncated and getMarker in particular have the same semantic (I have NO idea why they aren't actually factored out into a superclass or interface): the getX is slightly varied.

Comment: Gave you a heavy edit, please correct if I got something wrong.

Comment: There's an argument this goes on programmers.SE btw.

Answer (score 0):

Java is very unforgiving for you here. And why should it be forgiving? `Foo.baz` and `Bar.baz` are two methods with nothing in common. The names don't matter. You'll have to blame the library creators, who probably generated the source code for this and other AWS SDK languages from common code in another language.

It is also possible the Amazon developers were thinking of a target language like Javascript originally, in which case a common name would suffice for client code to be generic. The Java case may have been butchered.

Your options are:

1. Maintain your own wrappers.
2. Generate your own wrappers from smaller source, much like they (probably) did.
3. Use reflection. This can save you here, but I'm no expert in it so I can only suggest.

Note (1) is sadly common in the Java world, so don't be surprised if you go with it.

I also suggest posting on AWS' forums to see if anyone else has solved this. There may be a Java middleware some poor soul has written.